# Activiti list completed process

Tags: activiti

I'm starting to use activi inside my webapp write in java. How can I extract the list of completed jobs?
I tried to use runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().list(); but it does not show me the finished process.

Thank you
Sergio

Comment: Hi Sergio, what do you mean by Completed Job? You mean completed Processes? 
Because there is the concept of Job Execution as well. 
Have you checked the documentation in activiti.org? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir , I knew that TaskService.complete(taskId);

If you want to find out your finished task , why not use HistoryService , all variables and data included .

Such as HistoryService.create***Query , wish it could help you !